# How to get SUM of a column in below mysql table if I want to filter it by a product id, which is in a object array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, sum

I have a MySQL database and there I have an orders table as in below.
In here prc = product count, prid = product id and prcat = product category.

I want to get the sum of subtotal, where product id (prid) = 1 and category id (prcat) = 1.

```
    id, productDetails, subTotal, total
    -------------------------------------
    1   [{"prc": "1", "prid": 2, "prcat": 1}]   5000    5300
    
    2   [{"prc": "2", "prid": 2, "prcat": 1}, {"prc": "4", "prid": 1, "prcat": 3}]  30000   30300
    
    3   [{"prc": "1", "prid": 5, "prcat": 18}]  1000    1400
    
    4   [{"prc": "8", "prid": 5, "prcat": 18}]  8000    8300
    
    5   [{"prc": "1", "prid": 5, "prcat": 19}]  1000    1300
```

Comment: You'll need to use `JSON_TABLE()` to convert the JSON array into a table, then you can use `SUM()` to get the total. It would be easier if you normalized your tables instead of using JSON.